# Trying to clone a bare git repo: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

I set up a git user on my Mac OS 10.7 system. In the root, there's a `/repositories/test.git` repo. When trying to clone it with `git clone git@server:repositories/test.git` it fails me with:

```
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225291/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-how-to-fix-this-correctly for details, but essentially the server doesn't have `git-upload-pack` in the right directory for a non-login shell to execute.

Comment: The thing is that if I place the repo in my own users root, the clone succeeds. So, I'm thinking it might be a rights issue.

Comment: Although that actually solved my command line issues, Atlassian SourceTree still won't push. I think it's a different issue though.